# Is this a good way to use generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, methods

Following are my codes.

```
public class baseMenuItem : MenuItem
{        
    public baseMenuItem()
    {
        this.Click += baseMenuItem_Click;
    }

    void baseMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //When user click the menu, I will need to new a window which type is assigned from AssignHandleWindow<T>()
    }

    public void AssignHandleWindow<T>() where T : baseWindow 
    {
        //Can I save <T> into somewhere for later Click-event using?
        //How do I do that?
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible, but there could be 40 even more menuItems in my application, I don't want to write click event for each of them to open the window, any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide sample how it must work?

Comment: `When user click the menu, I will need to new a window` which means you already know which window to show. So, looks like inheritance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save Type in the field and use then like

```
public class baseMenuItem : MenuItem
{        
    Type windowType;
    public baseMenuItem()
    {
        this.Click += baseMenuItem_Click;
    }

    void baseMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(windowType != null){
            window = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);
            window.Show();
        }
    }

    public void AssignHandleWindow<T>() where T : baseWindow 
    {
        windowType = typeof(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection might be a better choice here. You can associate custom data with a control through the Tag property on the control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can assign the fully qualified type name of the window you want to open to the Tag (either through the designer or through code). Through code it would look something like this:

```
menuItem.Tag = "namespace.class, dllname";
```

And then do the following in the generic event handler (my Win Forms is a little rusty, but it should give you an idea of what you need to do):

```
void baseMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Control senderAsControl = (Control)sender;
    Type windowType = Type.GetType((string)(senderAsControl.Tag));
    Control window = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(windowType);
    window.Show();
}
```

Usual preamble of this being completely untested applies.

Comment: This is a great solution too, I tried and it works, I really want to mark it as answer however this website seems not allow me to do that(mark 2 answers), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public T AssignHandleWindow<T>() where T : baseWindow, new() 
{
    var window = new T();
    return window;
}
```

Can the above work?

You can then call this from the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I recently populated a drop down menu with

```
var thingsForMenu = getThingsForMenuBasedOnWhasClickedOn();
foreach(var v in thingsForMenu) {
    ToolStripItem ti = new ToolStripMenuItem(v.key);
    var localItem c = v.value;
    ti.onClick += (o,ie) => {
         doTheThing(c);
    }
    ToolStrip.DropDownItems.Add(ti);
}
```

note: the local variable copy of c is critical, as v is re-assigned inside the loop, and you need to pass a pointer to c in, not just whichever v.value happens to persist in memory after the function returns (typically resulting in all menu items calling the same thing)

This isn't quite the "how do i use generics" answer to your question, but does provide a mechanism to communicate information into the onClick handler.